# Node.js Command Line Console Log Level

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments

How do you set the log level for node when starting it from the command line? I admit, i'm a node.js newbie, but looking for something like `node myapp.js --loglevel warn`

Comment: What do you mean "the log level"?  As determined by what?

Comment: Node provides no intrinsic logging, other than printing an error message on unhandled exceptions, so there is no loglevel to set.

Comment: To add to what Rob said, the console.log/console.warn/console.err methods are just writers to stdout/stderr, there's nothing that uses those method names to determine if something is outputted or not.

Comment: thanks guys, i'm using this library now in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/visionmedia/log.js/

Comment: @kocodude but how do you filter the logs you see from `log.js` based on an env variable - as per your question ? ( I have the same question ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082365/control-which-logs-are-shown-in-console-based-on-environment-variable

Answer (score 5):

You can overwrite the `console.log`,`console.debug`,`console.error`,`console.warn` functions to allow logLevels.

Check out my snippet written in typescript:

```
export type LogLevel = "debug" | "log" | "warn" | "error" | "none";
let logLevels = ["debug", "log", "warn", "error", "none"];
let shouldLog = (level: LogLevel) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  return logLevels.indexOf(level) >= logLevels.indexOf(global.logLevel);
};

// @ts-ignore
global.logLevel = "debug";
let _console=console
global.console = {
  ...global.console,
  log: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => {
    shouldLog("log")&&_console.log(message, ...optionalParams);
  },
  warn: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => {
    shouldLog("warn") && _console.warn(message, ...optionalParams);
  },
  error: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => {
    shouldLog("error") && _console.error(message, ...optionalParams);
  },
  debug: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => {
    shouldLog("debug") && _console.debug(message, ...optionalParams);
  },
};
```

Then you can use the `console` functions as usual and set the logLevel with `globals.logLevel="warn"`,...

Answer (score 1):

Not possibly quite what you are after but you can enable debugging within node by setting a NODE_DEBUG environment variable first.

E.g. `export NODE_DEBUG="net" && node myapp.js` will give debugging for network related node operations.

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L66