# Control which logs are shown in console based on environment variable

Tags: node.js, logging

In my Node/NuxtJS stack, I use a standardized log structure which is:

```
{
  time: '2022-02-11T15:00:29.897Z',
  level: 'DEBUG',
  message: 'something',
}
```

I would like to be able to control which logs I see based on an environment variable I pass to the npm script, e.g. :

```
dev: LOGLEVEL=debug node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt
```

would only show logs with `level: 'DEBUG'`.

What do I need to do to achieve the above?

I also have the possibility to use [consola](https://github.com/unjs/consola) to wrap logs if necessary.